# Cascading parameters in SSRS reports doesn't work with one parameter value set to a default value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I'm trying to run an SSRS report with cascading parameters.
I have 2 parameters para1, para2.
I have made para1 as a hidden field and assigned para1 a default value.
I have set para2 to take available values from a dataset.
I'm trying to populate para2 drop-down based on para1's default value.
My query for populating para2 is

SELECT column2 FROM TABLENAME
WHERE (column1 = @para1)

(here column1, column2 from Database refer to respective para1, para2 parameters in report)

I have my query working fine with the database and I see filtered result but gives me an error when I click preview on BIDS.

Error:
**The report parameter ‘para2’ has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter “para1”. Forward dependencies are not valid.**

I'm unable to figure out where I'm going wrong. Please help me find my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of your parameters in the parameter list.

1. On the menu bar click View>Report Data
2. Then highlight one of the parameters and click the up or down arrow (depending on the highlighted param)

The up and down arrows are located at the top of the Report Data list. You should end up with Para1 being above Para2 in the parameters list.